# Reviews of Lee's "Abstract Algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

Has anyone read *Abstract Algebra: An Introductory Course (Springer Undergraduate Mathematics Series)* by Gregoy T. Lee? I cannot seem to find any opinions on this book.  It seems to be fairly new [Amazon link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Abstract-Algebra-Introductory-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/3319776487).

How would you say it compares with Fraleigh's book? Lee's book has 100 pages fewer but is also much cheaper.

Comment: I haven't looked at it and can't answer your comparison question but you can find a review of both on Zentralblatt Math https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1401.00003 https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1060.00001 which may help you make up your mind.

Comment: yeah found that one too...just wondering from an actual consumer/student. thank you.

Comment: Its one of the best books published in recent times and ideal for self study since it contains solutions for half of all exercises .

Comment: Really? in that case i will bookmark it .thank you,